# ¿Como seleccionar varios elementos con javascript en php?

Tags: javascript, php

Ejemplo :

```
$anio = "2021"

$DateAndTime = date('Y');
if ($anio != $DateAndTime) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.querySelectorAll('.borrar').style.display='none'</script>";
}
```

No me produce el cambio , en caso si lo hago con getElementById Si , De antemano Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Porque querySelectAll te crea una matriz de esos elementos. Deberias hacer algo similar a esto

```
 $DateAndTime = date('Y');
if ($anio != $DateAndTime) {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    const elementos = document.querySelectorAll('.borrar');
    elementos.forEach((e) => {
     e.style.display='none'
    })
    </script>";
}
```

querySelectAll busca todos los elementos que contengan la clase .borrar y te crea un array con ellos.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!